# OpenCV Video Capture nonfunctional as class member (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

My application requires that the OpenCV VideoCapture object be used as a member variable. There is no way around this requirement.

I am experiencing strange behavior when using `cv::VideoCapture` as a member of a user-defined class. I've run the following code:

```
#define int64 opencv_broken_int
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#undef int64


class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = default;
    void run(void) {
        cv::VideoCapture* cap = new cv::VideoCapture();
        cv::VideoCapture g_cap = *cap;
        if (not g_cap.open(0)) {
            std::cerr << "Cannot open camera 0" << std::endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (not g_cap.isOpened())
                std::cerr << "Video capture is not open here!" << std::endl;
            cv::Mat f;
            g_cap >> f;
            if (f.empty()) std::cerr << "Frame was empty" << std::endl; break;
            std::string filename = "Foo_test_" + std::to_string(i) + ".tiff";
            bool b = cv::imwrite(filename, f);
            if (not b) std::cerr << "Error in writing image" << std::endl;
            //cv::waitKey(25);
        }
    };

};

int main(void) {
    cv::VideoCapture cap;

    if (not cap.open(0)) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open camera 0" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
        cv::Mat frame; 
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty()) {
            std::cerr << "frame is empty" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        // Else write the image to a file
        std::string filename = "test_" + std::to_string(i) + ".tiff";
        bool res = cv::imwrite(filename, frame);
        if (not res) 
            std::cerr << "Error in writing image" << std::endl;

    }

    cap.release();

    Foo f;
    f.run();

    return 0;
}
```

which only produced test_N.tiff for N = [0,9], i.e., the only images produced are coming from the `cv::VideoCapture` object in `main( )` and *not* from within class `Foo`.

I tried to instantiate a global variable `g_cap` of type `cv::VideoCapture` and still I only can read/write images from the object within the main function. As shown in the above code I also tried to instantiate the VideoCapture object as a pointer (a hail mary, if you will) and that does not work either. Note however that setting `cap` declared in `main( )` to be a reference to `g_cap` (obviously when `g_cap` was in global scope) gave the same output - getting images from within `main( )` but not from within `Foo::run( )` as needed.

Note another strange behavior is that no error messages appear in the console. That would indicate that `Foo`'s member of type `VideoCapture` is in fact open and that loading an image frame into `f` of type `cv::Mat` did not return an empty frame. Similarly the `imwrite` function does not return false indicating that the operation was successful. However, as previously stated, no files of name Foo_test_N.tiff were produced.

How could this behavior be explained? Is there some requirement that `cv::VideoCapture` be in some different scope perhaps? If the images are not saved or the video stream is not opened correctly would this not produce an error message as the above code is written?

Edit 20201110_1:
In response to Viktor Latypov's comment below:
I've implemented the proposed changes and am still observing the same behavior. Edits:

```
class Foo {
public:
        Foo() = default;
        void run(void) {
                cv::VideoCapture* cap = new cv::VideoCapture();
                //cv::VideoCapture g_cap = *cap;
                if (not cap -> open(0)) {
                        std::cerr << "Cannot open camera 0" << std::endl;
                        exit(-1);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        if (not cap -> isOpened())
                                std::cerr << "Video capture is not open here!" << std::endl;
                        cv::Mat f;
                        *cap >> f;
                        if (f.empty()) std::cerr << "Frame was empty" << std::endl; break;
                        std::string filename = "Foo_test_" + std::to_string(i) + ".tiff";
                        bool b = cv::imwrite(filename, f);
                       if (not b) std::cerr << "Error in writing image" << std::endl;
                       //cv::waitKey(25);
                }
                cap -> release();
        };

};
```

Edit 20201110_2:
OpenCV Version is 4.2.0

I tried to capture image frames from (a) within a function and (b) passing the OpenCV VideoCapture object instantiated in `main( )` to a parameterized constructor both as a copy and passing the pointer with still the same results. Complete code is shown below:

```
#define int64 opencv_broken_int
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#undef int64


class Foo {
public:
        Foo() = default;
        void run(void) {
                cv::VideoCapture* cap = new cv::VideoCapture();
                //cv::VideoCapture g_cap = *cap;
                if (not cap -> open(0)) {
                        std::cerr << "Cannot open camera 0" << std::endl;
                        exit(-1);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        if (not cap -> isOpened())
                                std::cerr << "Video capture is not open here!" << std::endl;
                        cv::Mat f;
                        *cap >> f;
                        if (f.empty()) std::cerr << "Frame was empty" << std::endl; break;
                        std::string filename = "Foo_test_" + std::to_string(i) + ".tiff";
                        bool b = cv::imwrite(filename, f);
                       if (not b) std::cerr << "Error in writing image" << std::endl;
                       //cv::waitKey(25);
                }
                cap -> release();
        };

};


class Bar {
public:
        Bar(cv::VideoCapture* c) : cap(c) {};

        void run(void) {
                //cv::VideoCapture* cap = new cv::VideoCapture();
                //cv::VideoCapture g_cap = *cap;
                if (not cap -> open(0)) {
                        std::cerr << "Cannot open camera 0" << std::endl;
                        exit(-1);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        if (not cap -> isOpened())
                                std::cerr << "Video capture is not open here!" << std::endl;
                        cv::Mat f;
                        *cap >> f;
                        if (f.empty()) std::cerr << "Frame was empty" << std::endl; break;
                        std::string filename = "Bar_test_" + std::to_string(i) + ".tiff";
                        bool b = cv::imwrite(filename, f);
                       if (not b) std::cerr << "Error in writing image" << std::endl;
                       //cv::waitKey(25);
                }
                cap -> release();
        };

        cv::VideoCapture* cap;
};


void test(void) {
        cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

        if (not cap.open(0)) {
                std::cerr << "Cannot open camera 0" << std::endl;
                exit(-1);
        }

        for (int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
                cv::Mat frame;
                cap >> frame;
                if (frame.empty()) {
                        std::cerr << "frame is empty" << std::endl;
                        break;
                }
                // Else write the image to a file
                std::string filename = "testFunc_test_" + std::to_string(i) + ".tiff";
                bool res = cv::imwrite(filename, frame);
                if (not res)
                        std::cerr << "Error in writing image" << std::endl;

        }

        cap.release();
}

int main(void) {
        cv::VideoCapture cap;

        if (not cap.open(0)) {
                std::cerr << "Cannot open camera 0" << std::endl;
                return -1;
        }

        for (int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
                cv::Mat frame;
                cap >> frame;
                if (frame.empty()) {
                        std::cerr << "frame is empty" << std::endl;
                        break;
                }
                // Else write the image to a file
                std::string filename = "main_test_" + std::to_string(i) + ".tiff";
                bool res = cv::imwrite(filename, frame);
                if (not res)
                        std::cerr << "Error in writing image" << std::endl;

        }

        cap.release();

        Bar b(&cap); b.run();

        Foo f; f.run();

        test();

        return 0;
}
```

The output from this program is shown:
[image: Output from OpenCVTest Executable]
Note that no images are saved from within the class member functions of either `Foo` or `Bar`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT1:

The real problem is in this line

```
  if (f.empty()) std::cerr << "Frame was empty" << std::endl; break;
```

I have overlooked this obvious problem. The `break` statement executes no matter what the `f.empty()` check returns.

It should be

```
  if (f.empty())
  {
       std::cerr << "Frame was empty" << std::endl;
       break;
  }
```

===================

Former answer (problem N2) :

After allocating the `cap` object

```
    cv::VideoCapture* cap = new cv::VideoCapture();
```

you are calling the assignment operator

```
    cv::VideoCapture g_cap = *cap;
```

which may perform more actions than you actually want.

Remove the `g_cap` variable and use `cap` directly.

E.g., the line

```
    if (not g_cap.open(0)) {
```

should be

```
    if (not cap->open(0)) {
```

and the line

```
        g_cap >> f;
```

would become

```
        *cap >> f;   // or  cap->read(f);
```

After these simple modifications the `run()` method produces image files with grabbed frames.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I edited the original question as I'm still observing the same behavior.

Comment: I have edited the answer. The problem is actually way simpler and probably does not require previous changes. Tested and working on my side. Not a Tegra system, simple Ubuntu Linux desktop, but should be valid.

Comment: Thank you :) the moral of the story is don't overlook the simple mistakes!!